# WiFi Password: how is it stored and where?

Tags: android, wifi

Anyone knows how and where the WiFi passwords are stored on the android devices. I'm not looking into cracking it, but into saving and restoring whatever "container" holds it. any android API framework support to save wifi password and then retrieve the wifi password?

Answer (score 6):

It varies from device to device: it is stored in the `wpa_supplication.conf` configuration file, but that can be customized from distribution to distribution. [See for a couple of possible locations](http://alt236.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-wifi-password-locations.html), but you will need to dig around your device for it.

There is no API support for reading/writing Wifi passwords for APKs not signed with the system key, so no: you won't be able to retrieve it.

Comment: this one needs root access. how about without root access? any android framework?

Comment: No. There is no API or framework for retrieving network passwords.

Comment: Can you read them from the /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf as plain file ?

Comment: you can't access /data without root access

Comment: @Femi I remember having an application on my phone that showed the list of saved WiFi connections and their passwords. So it does exist, but it requires root access

Comment: It appears to be stored as "psk" as a very long hex string, how do I decode this to a format that Wil like work?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep "k=" /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf | sed '2!d'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's unclear how your answer solves the original problem. Could you provide some more detail to make this more clear?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need root access, a rooted device to see the files which are normally abstract the whole device information from the end user.
You can use a application like ES file explorer available on playstore.
Then allow root access to the ES file explorer and then turn on root explorer from the menu.
Here you go just go to local menu and click device button
data» misc» wifi » your wow file is here .!